# position:fixed cause margin-top disappear?

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

Things i want achieve is quite simple

- just at top a fixed position element that do not move while scrolling
  down the document.
- and after is a div#content have some margin-top    from the top edge
  and center in the window.

so the code is:
**html**

```
<div class='head-container' id="headerCom">
    <header id="a"></header>
</div>
<div id="content" role="main"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
 * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .head-container {
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        _position:absolute; // make the ie6 support the fixed position
        _top: expression(eval(document.documentElement.scrollTop)); // make the ie6 support the fixed position
    }
    header {
        display: block;
        width: 960px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        zoom: 1;
        background: blue;
    }
    #content {
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 130px auto 0 auto;
        width: 960px;
        height: 1000px;
        background: #999;
        margin-top: 150px;
    }
```

all the modern browser is well support,but in ie(ie7,ie8,ie10) do not work correctly,things is just like it ignore the margin-top i set to the div#content;

so far i have checkout the other question on stackoverflow,and i try almost everthing i could.

- **when i change the margin-top of the div#content to the padding-top,things okay.**
- **When i put a div.clear(clear:both)in between the div.header-container and the div#conetent,the things goes okay;**
- **Or i follow other questions' solution that it caused by the *hasLayout*, and then take out the width and height of the div#content, the things is also okay, but in this way, i will need to put another div#inner-content inside the div#content, and set width and height to it to see the result.**

so i am quite confused by the hasLayout, and i am not quite sure i am completely understand what it is and not quite sure what is happening in here in my code.

**So actually can all you help me with this, is there any other solution could fix this problem, and explain this wired things to me?**

**Thank you anyway.**

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me once I get rid of the last `margin-top` attribute. Do you know you have set it twice? Once with `margin` and them again with `margin-top`. If you edit just `margin`s first value it wouldn't work because the last one will override the first one.

Comment: Oh thanks for point this out! actually i know it, it's for test and i forget remove it pasting here, **and just a second i find that if i put the DIV.header-container under the DIV#content, it will work fine**...